# os.eventfd_read does not set counter back to zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I am using [`os.eventfd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.eventfd) (new in Python 3.10) for IPC between a C process and a Python process.  The Python process is run by `fork-execv` from C.

The `eventfd` and `epoll` are set up in C, and the `eventfd` file descriptor is passed to Python.

According to the [Linux docs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html): "If `EFD_SEMAPHORE` was not specified and the `eventfd` counter has a nonzero value, then a `read(2)` returns 8 bytes containing that value, and the counter's value is reset to zero." So I would expect that a read would occur once, then not again, or subsequent reads should return 0 after the first read.  But that's not what happens, it keeps returning the same value over and over again.

The C program sets up the eventfd and epoll:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/eventfd.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>

int eventfd_initialize()
{
  int efd = eventfd(0,0);

  return efd;
}

int epoll_initialize(int efd, int64_t * output_array)
{

  struct epoll_event ev;
  int epoll_fd = epoll_create1(0);

  if(epoll_fd == -1)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create epoll file descriptor\n");
    return 1;
  }

  ev.events = EPOLLIN; //May also need to be or'ed with EPOLLOUT
  ev.data.fd = efd; //was 0

  if(epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, efd, &ev) == -1)
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to add file descriptor to epoll\n");
      close(epoll_fd);
      return 1;
  }

  output_array[0] = epoll_fd;
  output_array[1] = (int64_t)&ev;

  return 0;
}

ssize_t epoll_write(int epoll_fd, struct epoll_event * event_struc, int action_code)
{
    char ewbuf[8];
    sprintf(ewbuf, "%d", action_code);
    int maxevents = 1;
    int timeout = -1;

    write(epoll_fd, &ewbuf, 8);

    epoll_wait(epoll_fd, event_struc, maxevents, timeout);

    return 0;
}
```

The C program writes to the eventfd before the Python script is initialized, then the Python script is called with `fork-exec`.  The Python script is a simple while True loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import os
from multiprocessing import shared_memory

event_fd = int(sys.argv[3])

os.set_blocking(event_fd, False)

existing_shm =  shared_memory.SharedMemory(name='shm_object_0_0',create=False)

while True:

    print("Waiting in Python for event")
    v = os.eventfd_read(event_fd)
    print("found")
    print(v)

    if v != 99:
        print("release semaphore")
        os.eventfd_write(event_fd, v)

    if v == 99:
        print("finally")
        os.close(event_fd)
```

So I would expect it to read once, then all subsequent reads would return zero before the C side has written more to the `eventfd`.  But I get this continuous display:

```
Waiting in Python for event
found
13361
release semaphore
Waiting in Python for event
found
13361
release semaphore
Waiting in Python for event
found
13361
release semaphore
Waiting in Python for event
found
13361
release semaphore
```

With each new read it returns the same number, not 0.  The docs say a read from the `eventfd` will set it back to zero.  Adding `time.sleep(1)` to Python doesn't change the behavior.

Also, I don't see any way to call `epoll_wait` in the Python [`os` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html).